# How do I forcibly unmount when I'm getting stale nfs file handles?

Tags: linux, nfs, mount

Got myself into a tricky situation.  Have aufs mounted at /mnt/1

```
aufs on /mnt/1 type aufs (rw,relatime,si=daab1cec23213eea)
```

I can't unmount the thing:

```
sudo umount -f /mnt/1
umount2: Stale NFS file handle
umount: /mnt/1: Stale NFS file handle
umount2: Stale NFS file handle
umount2: Stale NFS file handle
```

How do I unmount the mount point? (without rebooting the system)

(Note: aufs is on top of an openafs system rather than NFS.)

Comment: Got into a similar situation, and could reproduce it easily: just remove the rw branch of the AUFS filesystem, and boom, the AUFS mountpoint is completely hosed. `umount -f` or `umount -l` won't change a thing. I'm still looking for a solution as well.

Comment: @jpetazzo Check out my answer below, I finally was able to resolve this issue for myself without needing a reboot

Answer (score 7):

from `man 8 umount`:

```
   -f     Force   unmount   (in  case  of  an  unreachable  NFS  system).
          (Requires kernel 2.1.116 or later.)

   -l     Lazy unmount. Detach the filesystem from the filesystem hierar-
          chy  now,  and cleanup all references to the filesystem as soon
          as it is not busy anymore.  (Requires kernel 2.4.11 or  later.)
```

If `sudo umount -f /mnt/1` does not work, you can try `sudo umount -l /mnt/1`.

Comment: `-l` may take some time, right? Is there some additional option if `-f` doesn't work?

Comment: `-l` has worked (instantaneously) when `-f` hasn't.

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I have found a solution for my issue (same as the question). This is what did **NOT** work for me:

- `mount -t nfs -o remount /mnt/1`
- `umount /mnt/1`
- `umount -f /mnt/1`
- `umount -l /mnt/1`

Here is what **DID** work for me:

- `umount -lf /mnt/1`

If this does not work for you, ensure that you kill all processes currently tied to the mounted directory:

- `lsof | grep /mnt/1`
- `fuser -k /mnt/1`

The `-l` (**l**azy) option tells `umount` not to clean things up now. Without this option the mount point will be busy. Check out @Xupeng's answer for the `man` page details on the umount options.

Answer (score 1):

You can unmount this, despite stale file handle, with:

```
fusermount -u /mnt/1
```